# Xna Movement not working

Tags: c#, xna

Hey since 1 week I am coding C# Xna and I ran into a problem
I hope you can help me.
The problem is that I made a Main class where I draw everything and I have a class for Control's
But now the control's wont work.

Main Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace Pong_0._0._0._1
{
    public class Main : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        public Texture2D paddel1;
        public Texture2D paddel2;
        public Texture2D border1;
        public Texture2D border2;
        public Vector2 paddel1Pos;
        public Vector2 paddel2Pos;
        public Vector2 border1Pos;
        public Vector2 border2Pos;
        public static int ScreenWidth = 1024;
        public static int ScreenHeight = 768;
        Paddels pads;
        public Main()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = ScreenWidth;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = ScreenHeight;
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            pads = new Paddels();
            pads.Initialize();
            base.Initialize();
        }
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
            paddel1 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("BOP");
            paddel2 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("BOP");
            border1 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("BOB");
            border2 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("BOB");
            paddel1Pos = new Vector2(ScreenWidth / 16, ScreenHeight / 2 - paddel1.Height / 2);
            paddel2Pos = new Vector2((ScreenWidth - paddel2.Width) - ScreenWidth / 16 , ScreenHeight / 2 - paddel2.Height / 2);
            border1Pos = new Vector2(ScreenWidth / 2 - (border1.Width / 2) , ScreenHeight / 12);
            border2Pos = new Vector2(ScreenWidth / 2 - (border2.Width / 2), (ScreenHeight - border2.Height) - ScreenHeight / 12);
        }
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
        }
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();
            pads.Update(gameTime);
            base.Update(gameTime);
        }
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Tomato);
            spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
            spriteBatch.Draw(paddel1, paddel1Pos, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.Draw(paddel2, paddel2Pos, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.Draw(border1, border1Pos, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.Draw(border2, border2Pos, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.End();
            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Control Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace Pong_0._0._0._1
{
    public class Paddels
    {
        public Main main;
        public int SPEED = 2;
        public Paddels()
        { 
        }
        public void Initialize()
        {
            main = new Main();
        }
        public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            KeyboardState KBS = Keyboard.GetState();
            if (KBS.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
            {
                main.paddel1Pos.Y = main.paddel1Pos.Y + SPEED;
            }
            else if (KBS.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
            { 
            }
            if (KBS.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
            { 
            }
            else if (KBS.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
            { 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I could do it all in one class but I want to learn to use multiple classes and the never work.

Thanks and hope to hear from anyone soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new "main" in your "Paddles" class. This new "Main" object has no knowledge of the actual one.

To solve this, just pass in the existing one when creating the paddles like this:

```
pads.Initialize(this);
```

With your initialize function changed to:

```
public void Initialize(Main parent)
{
  main = parent;
}
```

In general though, you are breaking encapsulation by doing this. The "Paddles" class should hold all the textures, update logic, and draw logic for the paddle game objects. The main class shouldn't need any of that, since it is passing it off to the new class, and the "Paddles" class shouldn't need any knowledge of the "Main" class (at least in your example).

Please let me know if you would like any clarification or extra informatino.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your paddle position, and paddle texture inside of your paddle class.

Then you need to make the paddle draw itself using these values.